# Samsung S5 mini supports Gamepad through OTG?

Tags: usb-on-the-go, game-controllers, samsung-galaxy-s-5-mini

I saw a video and some discussion where people just plug and play gamepads on to Android phones.

I've got a Samsung S5 mini (SM G800F, Android 4.4.2, not rooted). Bought a wire USB SNES Clone + OTG from ebay, plugged to my phone but nothing happened: tested on games, an app to debug gamepads, with a different and new USB Gamepad etc; I thought the USB OTG was damaged, because I tested with two different usb gamepads, so I bought a new setup ( http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/301836055385 ) + a different OTG cable from a different manufacturer. It doesn't work!

Used this app to check for OTG support:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.btssm.doihaveotg

It's supported but no devices are listed / none found;

Devices tested:
http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/USB-OTG-Android-Phone-Mobile-Retro-Gaming-Controller-Gamepad-Snes-Style-Pad-/291568165867?hash=item43e2d123eb:g:K10AAOSwVL1V~Rtn

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/301836055385

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/331719411548

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/151860529835

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/262031124734

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Does the Samsung S5 mini supports Gamepad through OTG?

Answer (score 1):

There is a fix for this OTG here http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s5-mini/help/usb-host-otg-t2855675/page2 BUT you have to install a custom Kernel. I did this on mine and it means you cannot get the 5.1.1 update from your carrier. SO i had OTG working fin for a while. Then reset phone so i could update to 5.1.1 via KIES but now now OTG again. Not sure if I can use the customer Kernel with 5.1.1 , did it so long ago now id be no help helping anyone, but it is my 2 cents worth.