# Samsung s5 mini - delock cable mouse / keyboard not working

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, usb-on-the-go, external-keyboard, mouse

I am using a simple delock cable which I ordered on amazon:
[Delock Kabel Micro USB Typ-B Stecker gewinkelt > USB 2.0-A Buchse OTG 11 cm](https://www.amazon.de/Delock-Kabel-Stecker-gewinkelt-Buchse/dp/B006TCXLF4)

**Question:** When connecting Mouse/Keyboard through the cable to my Galaxy S5 Mini, it does not work. Am I missing something? or the cable is not working?

**P.S:** Every video on the web shows that you simply connect it via the cable and thats it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OTG needs to be supported at the kernel level and you device does not appear to have that with stock kernel as you can see from cursory [Google search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=samsung+S5+mini+otg+support&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=jrzLWNPNDMXN0ATHw5WICw#spf=1).

[Samsung S5 mini supports Gamepad through OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/138096/131553) offers a way of flashing a custom kernel to override this limitation pointing to a XDA thread. You would **need root** to attempt this

Perhaps some videos which claim OTG support have this kernel flashed or custom ROM enabling this.